# An application of Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

For every twice differentiable function $f : \mathbb R \to [-2 , 2]$ with $(f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2 =85$ then there exists $x \in (-4 , 4)$ such that $f(x) +f''(x) = 0$ and $f'(x)  \neq 0$.

Can anyone give me a hint to solve this problem ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch $f'(x) = 0$ in your example

Comment: I believe this is a JEE Advanced 2018 problem: A solution can be found [here](https://cms.fiitjee.com/Resources/DownloadCentre/Document_Pdf_319.pdf) (Q4 maths section)

Comment: @caverac  can you please explain how $f'(x) = 0$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Have you seen what has been done in the solution? TOTALLY WRONG...I wonder how people get into these kind of coaching institutes..

Comment: hint: let $f(x) = sin(\sqrt{85}x)$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: You can not prove one statement by an example...Right?@@AniruddhaDeb Deb

Comment: @caverac can you answer this?